# Xamarin Searchbar with MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

There are quite a few articles about how to use the Xamarin `SearchBar` with MVVM pattern. The problem is that all these articles bind the `PerformSearch` event to an MVVM command.

I think these days, most users expect to see some results as they type and not once they tap "Search". So, I tried using the Xamarin Community Toolkit's `EventToCommandBehavior` to bind the `TextChanged` event to my MVVM command. It looks like this:

```
<SearchBar
   x:Name="CompanySearch"
   Placeholder="Search companies..."
   PlaceholderColor="#777777"
   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBackground}"
   TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryDark}">
   <SearchBar.Behaviors>
      <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
         EventName="TextChanged"
         Command="{Binding SearchTextChanged}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference CompanySearch}}"/>
   </SearchBar.Behaviors>
</SearchBar>
```

This works nicely UNTIL the user taps "Cancel" on iOS. Then it crashes the app with the following error:

> Invalid type for parameter. Expected Type System.String, but received
> Type Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs

[image]

That's because the method that handles the search in my model view is expecting `string` which looks like this:

```
async Task On_Search_Text_Changed(string keyword)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword) && keyword.Length > 3)
   {
      var data = await _myApi.CompanySearch(keyword);
      if (data != null && data.Count > 0)
         Suggestions = new ObservableRangeCollection<CompanyModel>(data);
   }
}
```

Any idea how to handle the cancel event with `EventToCommandBehavior`? I'm also open to another approach for as long as I can perform the search on `TextChanged` and NOT on `PerformSearch`.

Comment: Why can't you change your method signature? `async Task On_Search_Text_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)` then check for the value being null inside the method: `if (textChangedEventArgs.NewTextValue == null)`? [xamarinforms-searchbar-which-event-does-the-cancelbutton-fire](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c383908-f288-4441-8743-59e42407dfaf/xamarinforms-searchbar-which-event-does-the-cancelbutton-fire?forum=xamarinforms) or if there is only the `TextChangedEventArgs`, utilize the property `NewTextValue`

Comment: I just didn't think that was a "clean-enough" approach but as Jason suggested in the answer, I just don't see any other way right now, other than NOT using the `SearchBar` control. So, I think I'll go with it for now until I figure out another solution. Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrap it in a `try/catch` to trap the exception, or try this

```
async Task On_Search_Text_Changed(object keyword)
{
   if (keyword is string) 
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this but don't you think it's a bit of a kludge?

Comment: maybe, so what?